# I'm trying to create a footer.php for child theme with little success - Using wordpress + oceanwp + elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, footer, elementor, child-theming

I've recently created a child theme for OceanWP using elementor page builder.
I have uploaded the folder through Filezilla FTP put in the theme's folder next to the parent. I created style.css and functions.php and added the appropriate code into each and all pages of the site load fine after clearing the cache on WP Rocket and Cloudflare CDN.

I then went to add a `footer.php` file (because I need to add some additional code to the file just before the `</head>` tag for an affiliate link) and this is where I got confused.

Should I copy the code from the parent `footer.php` and insert it into the child? (I did this and my margins got all messed up and css styling went beserk)

Should it be left blank until I add code that I need? (I did this and my footer disappeared and menus wouldn't work properly?!)

Should it be neither and do I need to add some sort on `action or enqueue script` in the `functions.php` of the child theme to allow footer to appear properly?

I'm doing this all so *when* and *if* I update the theme, these snippets of code aren't deleted from my server and site entirely.

Do I even need to do this and should I just add it to the parent footer.php file?

I'm very new to coding and know only small amounts of HTML,CSS and just starting to learn PHP.

Here's the code I have in my child theme function.php file

```
/**
 * Child theme functions
 *
 * When using a child theme (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development
 * and http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), you can override certain
 * functions (those wrapped in a function_exists() call) by defining them first
 * in your child theme's functions.php file. The child theme's functions.php
 * file is included before the parent theme's file, so the child theme
 * functions would be used.
 *
 * Text Domain: oceanwp
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API
 *
 */

/**
 * Load the parent style.css file
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
 */
function oceanwp_child_enqueue_parent_style() {
    // Dynamically get version number of the parent stylesheet (lets browsers re-cache your stylesheet when you update your theme)
    $theme   = wp_get_theme( 'OceanWP' );
    $version = $theme->get( 'Version' );
    // Load the stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'oceanwp-style' ), $version );
    
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'oceanwp_child_enqueue_parent_style' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: "I then went to add a footer.php file (because I need to add some additional code to the file just before the head tag for an affiliate link) and this is where I got confused."

"just before the tag head" has nothing to do with footer.php

Usually,

the file footer.php has something to do with "just before the tag body"

the file header.php has something to do with "just before the tag head"

I say usually, because in some themes header.php and footer.php call other files or functions.

So, first of all, be sure you are not confusing header.php with footer.php

If your goal is writing additional code before the tag head, copy header.php and put it in your child theme. Then modify that file.

Comment: My apologies. It was the end of a long day and I didn't copyedit my work. Yes I meant just before the closing body tag in the footer

Comment: If I am creating a child footer.php should the code match exactly what the parent code contains and then I edit it from there? Or do I start from scratch with an empty file and then it reads what it should from the child first then gets the rest from the parent. Isnt that's how it works? Or do I point to it from the child functions.php like it does with the css enqueue? I'm not entirely sure I understand the structure of how the child theme works and what files are required to make modifications

Comment: You have to copy footer.php and put it in your child theme exactly as it is. Then you change that file according to your needs. Nothing else.

Comment: Hey Jose, thanks for the simplification! I'll try that one more time.